# Attempting to install Flask python

Tags: python, flask, installation, pip

I'm a new beginner in attempting to learning coding beginning with Python first.
I'm attempting to install flask but continuously receiving "syntax" error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pguk.png)

Any help would be useful, please and thank you.

Comment: [python course](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_history_and_philosophy.php) tutorials

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax :

```
pip install flask or python -m pip install flask
```

Answer (score 0):

pip is a command line (shell) program. Not to be used in python prompt.

The correct use is to call it in the shell

As example:

```
$ pip freeze
```

example output for a django env application:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
asgiref==3.2.7
CacheControl==0.12.6
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
contextlib2==0.6.0
distlib==0.3.0
distro==1.4.0
Django==3.0.7
django-cors-headers==3.3.0
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
djangorestframework==3.11.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
ipaddr==2.2.0
lockfile==0.12.2
msgpack==0.6.2
packaging==20.3
pep517==0.8.2
progress==1.5
pyparsing==2.4.6
pytoml==0.1.21
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.22.0
retrying==1.3.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
urllib3==1.25.8
webencodings==0.5.1
```

Comment: If what I'm using is Python prompt, what Python should I be using in order to begin coding in Python then?

Comment: You should use python3. You could use some IDE for a better experience in development. But pip is only a package management application like php composer, npm from node or java maven.

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to make commands within a Python shell which are not valid python commands.

All your commands are valid, just use them directly in terminal :).

p.s. If you copy and paste the output with 3 back ticks on either side, it posts it all fancy like and dont have to link screenshots,

```sh
like this
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using these steps if you are new to flask:

1. First open your `cmd` and type `cd desktop` it will move your directory to `desktop` and nothing else.
2. Then use `mkdir mywebsite` it will create a folder for you on desktop having a name `mywebsite`
3. Then use `cd mywebsite` it will move your directory to your folder that you have just created.

The real fun starts from here!

4. now type `py -m venv env` it will create a virtual folder  having a name of `env`  inside your `mywebsite` folder

this is the folder where you are going to install `flask` `numpy` or any other library based on your need!

5. now type `env\Scripts\activate`
6. you will see a virtual environment has been created for you because `(env)` is showing at the start of directory
7. now you can use `pip install flask`, It will install flask for you but only for this project. If you want to create another project later on you have to repeat the above process.

The reason why I recommend you to follow these steps is because whenever you are going to work with flask for your `python` app a virtual environment is best suitable for the developers.

If you want a video guide of these steps and how to run your first website here is the youtube guide: [Follow this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjtW-wnXlUY&t=393s)

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit out of the python interactive prompt or mode. You can just type exit(). Then when you are back at the normal windows command prompt, to install flask you can do so with the command "pip install flask".